# Copying only tags' values rather than all tags on sorting

Tags: xslt

I have the xml which I need to sort by 2 tags: Type and NonRecurringCharges. The value of Type tag is not unique (there are 2 Product in my xml). The NonRecurringCharges tag can be missed in any Offerings. I have a XLT template but it sorts and copies tags' values rather than tags.

Hopefully someone can help with this.

XML:

```
<ContractSummary>
<OrderInfo>
    <IsMobileOnly>false</IsMobileOnly>
</OrderInfo>
<Offerings>
    <Type>Product</Type>
    <Name Language="NL">Cable Access</Name>
    <NonRecurringCharges>
        <Type>PostPaid</Type>
        <ThirdPartyFinancingId>CAAC0001</ThirdPartyFinancingId>
    </NonRecurringCharges>
</Offerings>
    <Offerings>
    <Type>OneTimeService</Type>
    <Name Language="NL">Cable Access</Name>
    <NonRecurringCharges>
        <Type>PostPaid</Type>
        <ThirdPartyFinancingId>CAAC0001</ThirdPartyFinancingId>
    </NonRecurringCharges>
</Offerings>
<Offerings>
    <Type>Product</Type>
    <Name Language="ZFR">Enlvement</Name>
</Offerings></ContractSummary>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="ContractSummary">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *[not(self::Offerings)]" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Offerings">
    <xsl:sort select="Type"  />
    <xsl:sort select="NonRecurringCharges"  />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>   </xsl:template>
```

As result, I have xml:

```
<ContractSummary>falseOneTimeServiceCable AccessPostPaidCAAC0001ProductEnlvementProductCable AccessPostPaidCAAC0001</ContractSummary>
```

I need xml:

```
<ContractSummary>
<OrderInfo>
    <IsMobileOnly>false</IsMobileOnly>
</OrderInfo>
<Offerings>
    <Type>OneTimeService</Type>
    <Name Language="NL">Cable Access</Name>
    <NonRecurringCharges>
        <Type>PostPaid</Type>
        <ThirdPartyFinancingId>CAAC0001</ThirdPartyFinancingId>
    </NonRecurringCharges>
</Offerings>
<Offerings>
    <Type>Product</Type>
    <Name Language="ZFR">Enlvement</Name>
</Offerings>
<Offerings>
    <Type>Product2</Type>
    <Name Language="NL">Cable Access</Name>
    <NonRecurringCharges>
        <Type>PostPaid</Type>
        <ThirdPartyFinancingId>CAAC0001</ThirdPartyFinancingId>
    </NonRecurringCharges>
</Offerings></ContractSummary>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the identity transformation as the base step e.g. in XSLT 3 by declaring `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` or in XSLT 1 and 2 by adding a template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```